# Sorted strings in C++ don't compare correctly?

Tags: c++, string, comparison, string-comparison

Essentially, I have two lists. List `A` has terms, and list `B` has terms that have been scrambled. I'm trying to unscramble `B` by making a copy of `A`, sorting each string in it, and then sorting the strings in `B` and matching them with the sorted versions of `A`. Then I can just take the index from the sorted `A` and find the original by putting the same index in `A`.

So far my code looks fine, but the strings never equal each other. I've tried every form of comparison I know, right now im doing `str1.compare(str2) == 0`.

My code:
I have `vector<string> lines` and `vector<string> keywords`. Then I have `vector<string> sorted_kws` which is `keywords` with everything sorted.

```cpp
// Finding matching strings
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sorted_kws.size(); j++) {
        if (lines[i].compare(sorted_kws[j]) == 0)
            cout << keywords[j] << ",";
    }
}
cout << endl;
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I also tried using `std::find` but that didn't work either.
Also, I printed out everything to make sure it looked right. The strings are the exact same and should definitely equal each other, but they don't.

Comment: did you try to use a debbuger?

Comment: Please post a minimal, but complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the more of the code, it's just a tiny bit difficult (i.e., impossible) to guess at exactly where your problem lies. That said, getting the basic idea to work is certainly possible.

I think I'd do it by defining a class that stores both the original and sorted forms of a string. When you do comparisons, it does the comparison based on the sorted form, but when you write it to a stream, it shows the original string:

```
class sorted_string {
    std::string sorted;
    std::string original;
public:
    sorted_string(char const *input) :sorted(input), original(input) {
        std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, sorted_string const &s) {
        return os << s.original;
    }

    bool operator<(sorted_string const &other) const { 
        return sorted < other.sorted; 
    }
};
```

Using this, the rest of the code becomes pretty trivial:

```
int main() {
    // create two sets of input strings:
    std::set<sorted_string> in1{ "xzy", "bac", "dffed", "iii", "iji" };
    std::set<sorted_string> in2{ "yxz", "cab", "yyy", "ffedd", "iop" };

    // print out the intersection based on sorted comparison:
    std::set_intersection(
        in1.begin(), in1.end(),
        in2.begin(), in2.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<sorted_string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

I suppose you could do the same using an `std::map<std::string, std::string>` by using the sorted version of a string as the key, and the original version as the mapped value, but at least offhand it seems like that's likely to result in more work rather than less.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out exactly what you want to do, but if you have two sorted vector's, and you want to know what matches in both, then you can use std::set_intersection() instead of looping.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// assume v1 and v2 are sorted
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVect;
StringVect getDifferences(const StringVect& v1, 
                          const StringVect& v2)
{
   StringVect theDiff;
   std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                         std::back_inserter(theDiff));
   return theDiff;
}

int main()
{
    StringVect v1;
    v1.push_back("a");
    v1.push_back("b");
    v1.push_back("c");
    StringVect v2;
    v2.push_back("a");
    v2.push_back("c");
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    StringVect dif = getDifferences(v1, v2);
    std::copy(dif.begin(), dif.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

The output is:

a c

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was splitting by `"\n"` when all the strings had stupid `"\r\n"`s.